# Syntax error converting the nvarchar value to a column of data type int

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 stored as nvarchar inside Level in my db.

I then have a dropdownlist with values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. When a user makes a selection (i.e 1) (Level.SelectedValue.ToString). This builds an sql query via a param like this:

```
"Select things From MBA_EOI Where level = 1"
```

When I run the select I get the following error:

```
Syntax error converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9' to a column of data type int.
```

I was under the impression that I was dealing with an Nvarchar field and the selected value as string, where does the int conversion come in?

p.s I have also tried Level.SelectedItem.ToString

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do with this query. If 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 are all stored in the same field what would selecting where '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9' = '1' be meant to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By including `level = 1` you are implying to SQL that you want a numeric comparison, and it's attempting to cast all the column values to ints. If you used `level = '1'` instead, you'd get a text comparison with no conversion.